# ¿Como ingresar variables en system?

Tags: c++

estoy intentando hacer un código en el que el usuario ingrese un numero y mediante el comando system(color) pueda cambiar el color.
Ya intente cambiar las variables a char, string, (no se si lo estuve haciendo bien), y me dan errores relacionados con los tipos de variables.
Cuando me logra funcionar, lo que pasa es que se van corriendo los carácteres, si ingreso el número dos, me le "lor" en vez de "color"
Este es el código:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int opcion;

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int seleccion;
    char color[20];
    do {
        cout<<"\n 1. Cambiar color "<<endl<<" 2. Salir"<<endl<<"\n Seleccione una opcion: ";
        cin>>opcion;
        switch(opcion){
            case 1: {
                cout<<"\n\t - CAMBIAR COLOR - ";
                cout<<"\n 0. Negro"<<endl<<" 1. Azul"<<endl<<" 2. Verde"<<endl<<" 3. Aguamarina"<<endl<<" 4. Rojo"<<endl<<" 5. Purpura"<<endl<<" 6. Amarillo"<<endl<<" 7. Blanco"<<endl<<" 8. Gris"<<endl<<" 9. Azul claro"<<endl;
                cout<<"\n Ingrese el color que desea: ";
                cin>>seleccion;
                seleccion = itoa(seleccion.c_str());
                color[20]="color "+seleccion;
                system(color);
                break;
                }   
            case 2:
                cout<<"\n Aplicacion finalizada! "<<endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"\n Opcion incorrecta!!";
                break;
        }
    } while (opcion!=2);
}
```

Agradecería una respuesta.

Comment: tu comentario debe ser parte de la pregunta.

Comment: Ya lo pude hacer, por si alguien esta interesado, me pide el código.

Comment: No esperes que alguien te pida el código, en SO si tienes una respuesta a tu pregunta debes publicarla como respuesta y marcarla como correcta asi la respuesta será util para toda la comunidad :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
color[20]="color "+seleccion;
```

`+` no sirve para concatenar `char *`.

El compilador identifica `"color "` como un puntero a carácter, (`char *`) que apunta a un buffer que contiene los caracteres 'c', 'o', 'l', 'o', 'r', '\0'.

El `+ seleccion` suma 2. Al puntero (aritmética de punteros). Así que el puntero avanza dos caracteres y queda apuntando a la 'l' del buffer arriba mencionado.

En todo caso, la expresión sigue siendo `char *` y tú la asignas a `color[20]`, que es `char`. Esto es **comportamiento indefinido** (*undefined behavior*, UB). C no explica como tiene que comportarse el programa, así que el resultado puede ser cualquier cosa.

Si quieres trabajar con cadenas de caracteres a la manera de C (`char[]` y `char *`), usa las funciones existentes para ello (`strcpy`, `strcat`, etc). Aparte, en C++ puedes usar con `string` (que sí sobrecarga `+` para que signifique concatenación) y hacer `c_str()` cuando necesites obtener el valor como un `char *`.

Los expertos que tenemos en C++ veo que recomiendan el uso de `string`, así que te recomiendo lo mismo. En todo caso, hagas una cosa o la otra, por favor repasa lo que son punteros y arrays en C/C++ y las diferencias entre ambos.

Una nota importante es que este código que muestras tiene que estar mostrando muchos *warnings* pero parece que tú no les haces caso, posiblemente por desconocimiento. Los *warnings* suelen dar información útil; muchas cosas que en otros lenguajes de programación serían errores de compilación en C/C++ son *warnings*.

No ignores los *warnings* a no ser que sepas qué te están indicando y veas que no van a afectar a tu programa.

Comment: En todo caso, recomiendo que cuando tengas un problema te tomes un tiempo para analizar cuál es realmente el problema, y escribir la pregunta en consonancia. Este problema no tiene nada que ver con `system` sino con como se forma el comando; si hubieras imprimido el comando que se obtiene lo habrías visto y hubieras podido encontrar preguntas que te ayudaran.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, pero quiero matizar algo: "*`+` no sirve para concatenar `char *`*" eso es cierto salvo en el caso que alguno de los operadores de `+` sea un `std::string`.